# SQL Diagram Design Question - How I can manage each member's schedule in database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, primary-key

I'm building my own application for managing each member's schedule and tasks. For example,:

```
User(1) - 2019/6/22 - Task 1 - 80% Done
User(1) - 2019/6/22 - Task 2 - 50% Done 
User(1) - 2019/6/23 - Task 1 - 30% Done

User(2) - 2019/6/22 - Task 5 - 40%
```

Something like this. Very similar with google calendar.

One problem i am struggling with is that...Primary key.
What i learned about Relational database is that I need to keep primary key for best practice.

So, my current table is like this:

```
User Table      Daily Life Table       Task Table 
user id             Date(PK)             Task ID
detail info         user ID              user ID
                                         task name
```

This is just mock up, but I am curious about how I should make a daily life table because it is going to duplicate due to many users.

Is there any suggestion for this?

Comment: What is daily life? How does that relate to tasks and users?

Comment: If I am understanding your database structure, then Daily LIfe is related to specific tasks which are perfomed by a user on a given Date? Are you concerned with creating the Primary Key in table Daily Life? If so, you can create a composite primary key which could be composed of User ID Task ID and Date. You have a many to many relationship between Task and User, and Daily Life would basically be your junction table between the two including the date value with User ID and Task ID to form a unique primary key. Unless of course you could have a user perform the same task in a

Comment: given time frame (date) in which case you would need to either not use a primary key in the Daily Life table and just hold foreign keys to User and Task for table joining and then use the Date column for filtering purposes.

Comment: Off-topic for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is too broad--it asks for us to write a textbook & tutorial. ("keep primary key for best practice" & "going to duplicate" sound like rumours you repeat using terms you don't understand.) Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & DB design.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. PS Many such basic questions are nevertheless faqs.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks man. I'm considering in multiple ways. Daily life table basically has each date information and certain tasks for each user. Basically, you can think of this database as a calendar.   If I can do this easy way, I just can make a table for Calendar which includes everyday from janurary to december.

Comment: @KevinPark No problem. Hope I was able to help in some way. Good luck.